# Getting error "Upgrade an app to Lightning Experience to personalize it". Any thoughts?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-apps, salesforce-classic

When I clicked the blue "i" symbol in Lightning Experience I got an issue,

> "Ask your admin to upgrade this app to Lightning Experience so you can
>   personalize it"

Please see the screenshot below. Please give me some hint on how to resolve this. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is the app you are right now in a *Classic*  app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic applications can be made visible in Lightning, but they don't offer the same capabilities as Lightning apps. You can "upgrade" (really, clone) a Classic App into a Lightning App to add those capabilities - specifically, the user's ability to customize the tab set. The little "i" icon is meant to surface this fact, not to indicate any serious error that needs attending to.

It so happens that the Salesforce Chatter app is a Classic app - I see the same behavior in my Developer edition org. You can disable the application from visibility in Lightning Experience if necessary. The Chatter tab can be (and is) included in other Lightning applications. Because Salesforce Chatter is a built-in app, it doesn't appear that you can "upgrade" it in the same way you can other classic apps, so the message is a bit misleading.

The ["Getting Started with Lightning Apps"](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_apps/units/lightning_apps_intro) Trailhead has good information on what is offered on the Lightning app side. Note this caveat:

> Help users get the most out of personalized navigation by upgrading your Classic apps to Lightning apps. Users can’t personalize the navigation bar of Classic apps in Lightning Experience.

Comment: Thanks, David for the detailed explanation. As you said, it is showing an alert for the built-in app Salesforce chatter itself. Is that means that Salesforce Chatter is still not compatible with Lightning Experience? What it means if there is no Upgrade option given in the drop down. For some classic app, I am seeing options like Edit and Delete. But, I have not seen an Upgrade option for any of classic apps as per this article https://admin.salesforce.com/pro-tip-upgrade-salesforce-apps-lightning-experience. Am I missing something? I logged in as System Administration. Please advice.

Comment: @Bforce, no, it doesn't mean that Chatter isn't supported in Lightning - just that this specific App (set of tabs) is not a Lightning App, and hence in Lightning Experience cannot be edited like other Lightning Apps.

Comment: You can just turn the app off in Lightning if you prefer and create your own Lightning App including the Chatter tab.